# Any selector using * failed in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="cd1"></div>
<div class="cd2"></div>
<div class="cd3"></div>
<div class="cd4"></div>
<div class="cd5"></div>
```

How can I select base on 'cd' char?

```
I tried $('.cd*) but doesn't work.
```

Comment: give all div same class 'cd' and use $('.cd')

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia come on, my class is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the classes containing a specific text at the beggining:

```
$("[class^=cd]")
```

and To access the classes containing a specific text at the end:

```
$("[class$=cd]")
```

Comment: thanks, but can this be used together with $(this)? I want to check targeted hasClass($("[class^=cd]")).. possible?

Comment: If you have a specific element to check this on, you could use the `contains()` on the targeted element! as I have shown in http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/puhuh2ue/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the attribute class:

```
$('[class^=cd]')
```

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* use `$("[class^=cd]")`, it would be *very fragile* and it's not a good idea: As soon as you add other classes, you could break it. These would **fail** to match it, for instance:

```
<div class="foo cd1"></div>
<div class="bar cd2"></div>
```

Instead, add a second class to all of these elements that doesn't vary:

```
<div class="cd cd1"></div>
<div class="cd cd2"></div>
<div class="cd cd3"></div>
<div class="cd cd4"></div>
<div class="cd cd5"></div>
```

Then use `$(".cd")`.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with div, add some class to it

**example:**

```
 <div class="cd">
    <div class="cd1"></div>
    <div class="cd2"></div>
    <div class="cd3"></div>
    <div class="cd4"></div>
    <div class="cd5"></div>
 </div>
```

then you can use this selector $('.cd > div)